# MODX Revo: Проверить авторизацию пользователя при вызове ресурса

Tags: modx, revo, ресурсы

Переделываю сайт из шаблона.
На странице есть кнопка "Добавить". Если пользователь уже авторизован, то открывается нужная страница, иначе всплывает окно авторизации. Вот код кнопки:

```
 [[!+modx.user.id:gt=`0`:then=
`<a href="[[~35]]?cat=18" class="btn" id="add">Добавить</a>`
:else=
`<a><button class="btn" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logIn">Добавить</button>
</a>`]]
```

В одном месте сайта есть группа кнопок со ссылками на страницы, которые в менеджере модекса определены как ресурсы. Вот так:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 menu">
            [[pdoMenu?
                &parents=`0`
                &level=`1`
            ]]
        </div>
```

Нужно к ним добавить эту кнопку.

Ресурс я создал, как перенаправить оттуда пользователя на авторизацию, если он ещё её не прошел и открыть нужную страницу, если прошёл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надеюсь правильно вас понял.
pdoMenu по умолчанию имеет шаблон для вывода ссылок в сниппете:

```
@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>
```

Чтобы сделать проверку, вам нужно подключить свой шаблон в вызове через чанк и в нем уже проверять, например:

**чанк menuTpl:**

```
[[!+modx.user.id:gt=`0`:then=`
<!-- Стандартный шаблон генерации ссылок в pdoMenu -->
<li[[+classes]]><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>
`:else=`
<!-- Тут уже вывод кнопки или любой другой вариант -->
<li[[+classes]]><button class="btn" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logIn">Добавить</button></li>
`
]]
```

А сам вызов теперь будет таким:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 menu">
    [[pdoMenu?
    &parents=`0`
    &level=`1`
    &tpl=`menuTpl`
    ]]
</div>
```

где в **tpl указан наш чанк**, созданный ранее.

Comment: А как в этом menuTpl сделать, чтобы проверка работала только на эту кнопку? А остальные остались как и было? И внешне она не отличалась от других, разве что надписью. Другими словами, надо эту отдельную кнопку "добавить" тупо перенести с одного места страницы в pdoMenu

Comment: Руслан Алеев, на основе Вашего ответа заменил pdoMenu и просто прописал все строки вручную, добавив свою.

Comment: Здравствуйте, не совсем понял задачу изначально. Это условие проверки можно прописать в любом месте, и в шаблоне, обернув, например, вызов меню ссылок, и в чанке конкретного пункта меню.
Я думал, что нужно именно все пункты меню заменить на кнопку по условию.